# ReCaptcha v3 not feeding response token object in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, captcha

I'm working on an MVC .Net application.
We introduced reCaptcha v3 in it recently, it works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but not at all in IE.
Here is the code contained  in the header section:

```
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=@ViewBag.CaptchaSiteKey"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    grecaptcha.ready(function () {
        var test = grecaptcha.execute('@ViewBag.CaptchaSiteKey', { action: '@ViewBag.CaptchaEnvironment'+'_' + '@ViewBag.CaptchaActionName'}).then(
            function (token) {
                // verify the token on the server
                document.getElementById("RecaptchaResponse").value = token;
            }, function (reason) {
                document.getElementById("RecaptchaResponse").value = reason;
            });
    });
    </script>
```

The Viewbag variables are set as expected, nothing is missing.

The object that need to be fed is created in the form contained in my body section:

input id="RecaptchaResponse" name="RecaptchaResponse" type="hidden" autocomplete="off"

But remains empty when using in IE11.

I've read many articles that were kind of speaking about such behavior, but nothing worked.

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Try to use F12 developer tools to debug your code, whether it contains some error? 

Please check the IE browser Compatibility view, try to remove "google.com" from the Compatibility view. More details information, please check the [reCAPTCHA isn't displaying properly on Internet Explorer, what do I do?][1] 


  [1]: https://support.google.com/recaptcha/answer/6223838?hl=en&ref_topic=6188330#

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  The `execute` function returns null. It never calls the api. Did you resolve this??

Answer (score 3):

Google reCAPTCHA v3 utilizes "[JavaScript Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises)" in order to function properly.

In your code example, `grecaptcha.execute(...)` is issuing a "promise" for a token.  Once that promise is "fulfilled", the `.then(function() { ... })` portion of your code is executed.

Modern versions of Chrome/Firefox support JavaScript Promises.  Unfortunately, IE11 does not.  In order for promises to work on IE11, you would need to include a polyfill (see: https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise).

Comment: Thanks for this. I added the poyfill here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise). Basically added the two minified files (es6-promise.min.js and es6-promise.auto.min.js) in my <head> section but still reCaptcha is not working. Anything I'm missing or any other ideas?

Comment: Weird, I'm using reCAPTCHA v3 but I haven't added a polyfill anywhere. Is it included in the reCAPTCHA js file by any chance?